# pythonic way to setup logging with a module involved

Tags: python, logging

I wrote a simple `bot.py` that defines a logger.  The logger worked fine.

But then I needed to keepalive the `bot.py` script, so I wrote a `keepalive.py` that is called hourly and uses a sockets to identify when `bot.py` died, and restart it.

But I don't see the right/pythonic way to setup and share the logger between `keepalive.py` and `bot.py`.

I experimented with trying to pass the logger instance to `bot.py` when it's called from the `keepalive.py`, and otherwise creating it (if `bot.py` is run directly), but it would require me pass around the logger as a parameter to all the functions I call (example, the `demo()` function). This is gross.

Whats the best way to setup a logger once, and then use it everywhere else without doing too much passing around, etc?

`bot.py`

```
import logging

def demo():
    #this won't work unless I pass in the logger as a parameter
    #logger.info("demonstrate the Inner demo() called from Inner main works")
    pass

def main(logger=None):
    if logger is None:
        # Enable logging
        logging.basicConfig(
            filename='log_experiment.txt',
            format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
            level=logging.INFO)
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.info("I created logger instance inside Inner Main()")
    else:
        logger.info("I am using the logger passed to Inner main() as a parameter")

    demo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`keepalive.py`

```
import logging
import socket
import sys


# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='log_experiment.txt',
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("I created logger instance inside keepalive")

lock_socket = None  # we want to keep the socket open until the very end of
                    # our script so we use a global variable to avoid going
                    # out of scope and being garbage-collected



def is_lock_free():
    global lock_socket
    lock_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        lock_id = "straits.keepalive"   # this should be unique. using your username as a prefix is a convention
        lock_socket.bind('\0' + lock_id)
        logging.debug("Acquired lock %r" % (lock_id,))
        return True
    except socket.error:
        # socket already locked, task must already be running
        logging.info("Failed to acquire lock %r" % (lock_id,))
        return False

if not is_lock_free():
    print("alive")
    sys.exit()

print("**RESTART REQUIRED")
# then, either include the rest of your script below,
# or import it, if it's in a separate file:
import inner as bot

bot.main(logger)
```

Comment: Normally you define a logger at each module just after imports: `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`  Please read https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html for more.